# How to retrieve all essential cookies used by Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, cookies

I need to display all cookies that Joomla uses. I tried `print_r(headers_list)` and I got this

> Array ( [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.12 )

So I tried `print_r($_COOKIE)` and I got this:

> Array ( [12ecc9e8acc559e29bf3fafd5f5fe3df] =>
>   mta3apurfklkcufan01svecgvv )

So, does Joomla normally use essential cookies? If so, how can I get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You retrieve cookies in Joomla 3 by:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie->get('cookiename');
```

The cookie set in your `print_r($_COOKIE)` is the session cookie, this is usually referenced by:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->getId();
```

Other cookies will be set depending if you the user is logged in, and a multitude of others depending on 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Thank you. The result I got: `d2cm65jvet4r957n7fb024p7ru`. So basically Joomla doesn't have any active cookie to track the user?

Comment: This is the session cookie; so yes, it is used to "track" the user while their session is alive. As per your Session Lifetime set in Global Configuration, the session will be destroyed and a new session created upon expiry.

Comment: Ok thank you. I need to display a GDPR page that's why I asked this question. I didn't know what cookies Joomla uses.

Comment: Why not just use Joomla's native Privacy component for handling GDPR? You are GDPR compliant if you do *not* use user registration or any other component which captures data from the user because the session ID is pseudonymous.

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know about this. No I don't use any component. If I do it's my own components.